# abstract class arrays and oop design - Java

Tags: java, oop, hashmap, abstract

I have a class component

```
abstract class Component{
    private componentType m_type;

    public Component(componentType type)
    {
        m_type = type;
    }
}
```

and 2 subclasses

```
class AmplifierComponent extends Component{
    public AmplifierComponent()
    {
        super(componentType.Amp);
        System.out.print(this.m_type);
    }
}

class AttenuatorComponent extends Component{
    public AttenuatorComponent()
    {
        super(componentType.Att);
        System.out.print(this.m_type);
    }
}
```

my problems are:
1.i can't instantiate any kind of component because m_type isn't visible(what that means?)
2.i need to make an array of all the components the user has insert to the chain. i can't manage to create an array of Component class.

can someone help me with the design?
or with some workarounds?

Thanks in advance

Comment: make m_type protected instead of private, so that subclasses can see it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why you need the type member. This looks redundant. You can instead simply do:

```
abstract class Component{
}

class AttenuatorComponent extends Component{
    public AttenuatorComponent() {
       // calls the default super constructor
    }
}
```

and rely on [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) for your classes to behave appropriately. Having a type member to identify a hierarchy type is unnecessary when you've declared the corresponding classes. If you do have a member variable that is required to be visible in subclasses but not by clients, then you can make it `protected` rather than `private`.

`Component` could be an interface if there's no functionality/data associated with it.

Your array declaration would look like

```
Component[] components = new Component[20];
components[0] = new AttenuatorComponent();
```

Polymorphism would mean that you can iterate through this array of components, calling appropriate methods declared on (but not necessarily implemented by) the `Component`, and the suitable subclass methods would be called.

Comment: +1, also consider using an Interface instead of an abstract class if `Component`'s subclasses do not share any identically implemented functions.

Comment: why type is unnecessary? how can i determine what kind of component it is when i iterate through the array?

Comment: Just call a method on it. Java's polymorphism will determine the correct implementation method for you, depending on the type of the class

Answer (score 0):

Set m_type to protected to be able to see it from child classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Component {
    private componentType m_type;

    public Component(componentType type)
    {
        m_type = type;
    }

    public componentType getType()
    {
        return this.m_type;
    }
}

class AmplifierComponent extends Component{
    public AmplifierComponent()
    {
        super(componentType.Amp);
        System.out.print(super.getType());
    }
}

class AttenuatorComponent extends Component{
    public AttenuatorComponent()
    {
        super(componentType.Att);
        System.out.print(super.getType());
    }
}
```

That way you can read m_type, but cannot change it.
You could also make the getType() command protected, so it is only reachable through the classes which inherit it.